# Tomcat on spring is not loaded

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am working on spring in eclipse.When I run my server,it shows error is given below:

error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7d8d6983]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4889c18]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
>   (bad signature)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Dec 14, 2016 12:06:37 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
>   Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that
>   were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs
>   during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. Dec
>   14, 2016 12:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Dec 14, 2016 12:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.o7.planning</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
      <!-- Generic properties -->
      <java.version>1.7</java.version>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>


  <repositories>
      <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
      <repository>
          <id>codelds</id>
          <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>

  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Seems like one of the jar is corrupted. Try to clean .m2 directory(Located in your home directory) and rebuild and deploy your application

Comment: Thanks @SangramJadhav. Just nuked my .m2 directory and updated the maven dependencies and works like a charm

Comment: Thank you @SangramJadhav!  That fixed an issue for me I was stuck on for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the server and then again add new tomcat server and run it. For me this worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues sometimes. After adding new dependencies to POM file, maven downloads jars and if any jar got currupted due to some reason, the tomcat failed to start.

As @Sangram Jadhav suggested, remove the jars which are newly downloaded. OR

If you are not sure then only remove the .m2 folder.

Also there is issue with Tomcat as well where it failed to start after this thing happen, so delete the Tomcat which you are configured with eclipse. Set it up again. The tomcat will start.

Try this step first like to reset Tomcat settings in Eclipse otherwise delete the jars from .m2 or delete complete .me folder.

Hope this will help to someone.